# PHP IRC client for inclusion in web page

Tags: php, chat, irc

Does anyone know whether PHP can be used to include an IRC channel in a web page, so that visitors to the website can login to the IRC and communicate with each other.

Thanks.

Comment: I see a lot of entries in google. But I wont play with IRC in PHP, as IRC has a very bad history on security. Doing mashups can open up your PHP to breaches. Why do yo need this inclusion?

Comment: @Elzo: Cheers for the information.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: This was a question related to programming in PHP. I'm not requesting a complete solution, but was wondering whether there were any libraries available, or even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to create what you want: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1409-PHP-IRC-client-for-creating-chats-or-bots.html

Comment: Interesting thanks for the link.

Comment: It doesn't do anything. There no examples or documentation.